# UNIX shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix

currently I'm working on 2 code :

the first code is a code to display a menu to the user (start.sh) :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo choose a number :
echo "1.)display place information"
echo "2.)look for first character entered"

read number

case $number in
"1") ./script.sh;;
"2") ./script2.sh;;
esac
exit
```

the code for script.sh is :

```
#!/bin/sh
grep "$1" Place.txt
```

basically, when running script.sh , I need to enter 1 argument like `./script.sh home` and it match the word 'home' in Place.txt.

But , when i run the "start.sh" script and choose number 1 which run "script.sh" script I have nowhere to enter the argument (home) and the "script.sh" code won't run.

any suggestion how to achieve that?

Comment: You presumably need to prompt for the word in `start.sh` and then pass it as an argument to `script.sh`.  `read info` and `./script.sh "$info"`.

Comment: oh yes , that's what I was trying to achieve ! it works now. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

### You can either read the input from start.sh:

**start.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo choose a number :
echo "1.)display place information"
echo "2.)look for first character entered"

read number

case $number in
"1") echo "Please input argument"; read p; ./script.sh "$p";;
"2") echo "Please input argument"; read p; ./script2.sh "$p";;
esac
exit
```

### Or do it in script.sh:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Please input argument"
read p
grep "$p" Place.txt
```

Just dont do both.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to call another shell script when you can do it in one?

```
echo choose a number :
echo "1.)display place information"
echo "2.)look for first character entered"

read number

case $number in
1) read -p "Enter pattern to search: " search
   grep $search file.txt
   ;;
2) ;;
esac
exit
```